# OAuth client authentication for public clients

Tags: oauth-2.0, authentication

Good morning,

I spent quite some time researching the OAuth 2 spec and its different grant and client types. I haven't found a satisfying answer though for the question of how to authenticate public clients (i.e. mobile installed apps) using client secrets.

I also looked at FB and Google and realised that they use the bundleID (iOS) and public signing key (Android).

Can anyone explain how the client auth works in these cases, how this complements/fits in with the OAuth 2.0 spec and how security loop holes are avoided (i.e. decompilation of mobile app code) ?

thx Nick

Answer (score 2):

The short answer: public clients are not authenticated in OAuth 2.0.

The specification clearly distinguishes confidential (usually webapp) and public (usually embedded) clients. Confidential clients use the authorization code grant scenario with maximal security and authenticate. However, applications installed on a user device, especially javascript apps could not properly hide their client_secret and a received authorization code, so the standard made a simplified scenario for them: the implicit grant flow.

In this scenario, no client_secret or code => token exchange is needed. Note that it's essentially less secure by design because embedded applications themselves are essentially less secure, so steps where security cannot be protected are simply omitted. The client uses just its client_id without a client_secret and immediately retrieves a token from the authorization endpoint instead of an authorization code. Some safety is still present in the scenario by using https, explicit authorization of the request by the user and returning the results to a registered redirect_uri. Note that the specification forbids issuing a refresh token in this scenario for safety reasons.

Comment: thanks for that. Maybe to clarify my question: I am aware of the security limitations for public clients from an OAuth perspective which basically results in two alternatives: Either don't trust the application (i.e. don't provide access to sensitive data/activities) or implement addditional security measures outside of OAuth. If option 1 is not a valid option (as I don't want to limit mobile capabilities), what additional security measures exist in order to treat a mobile app as a confidential client. Hence my reference to Google and Facebook which seem to apply additional means (bundleID).

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood then. Frankly I'm not very familiar with this bundleID and similar mobile extensions, we'll need someone else to help you out here.

Comment: As we discussed in these comments, I seemed to slightly misunderstand the question and I cannot properly answer. Can you suggest an appropriate solution? Should I delete this answer?